# NGDOC - top-down hierarchy

Tags: angularjs, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3, ngdoc

I have a large AngularJS project which is documented with NGDOC. We have lots of forms, and specific directives can be included only in specific forms. This is now documented as dependencies - each directive has @requires my.directive:myFormContainerBlaBla inside of its comment. Generated documentation for this directive contains the appropriate link to the myFormContainerBlaBla in dependencies section.

However, the documentation for the myFormContainerBlaBla does not contain any reference to the directives which may be used inside of it. Menu List of documented directives is also flat. Is there a way to do that:

1) Documentation for myFormContainerBlaBla contains links to all directives which @require it.

2) The menu list of documented directives is hierarchically arranged, i.E.

```
myFormContainerBlaBla
  directive1
  directive2
  directive3
myFormContainerBlaBla2
  directive4
  directive3
  directive5
```